# Where is the Chinese character "" in a java .class file

Tags: java, unicode

I have such a java class:

```
public class UnicodeTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "中";
            String s1 = "";
            System.out.println(s.length());
            System.out.println(s1.length());
            System.out.println(s1.toCharArray().length);
        }
    }
```

then I use xxd to see the compiled class file:

```
0000000: cafe babe 0000 0032 0031 0700 0201 000b  .......2.1......
0000010: 556e 6963 6f64 6554 6573 7407 0004 0100  UnicodeTest.....
0000020: 106a 6176 612f 6c61 6e67 2f4f 626a 6563  .java/lang/Objec
0000030: 7401 0006 3c69 6e69 743e 0100 0328 2956  t...<init>...()V
0000040: 0100 0443 6f64 650a 0003 0009 0c00 0500  ...Code.........
0000050: 0601 000f 4c69 6e65 4e75 6d62 6572 5461  ....LineNumberTa
0000060: 626c 6501 0012 4c6f 6361 6c56 6172 6961  ble...LocalVaria
0000070: 626c 6554 6162 6c65 0100 0474 6869 7301  bleTable...this.
0000080: 000d 4c55 6e69 636f 6465 5465 7374 3b01  ..LUnicodeTest;.
0000090: 0004 6d61 696e 0100 1628 5b4c 6a61 7661  ..main...([Ljava
00000a0: 2f6c 616e 672f 5374 7269 6e67 3b29 5608  /lang/String;)V.
00000b0: 0011 0100 03e4 b8ad 0800 1301 0006 eda1  ................
00000c0: a4ed b480 0900 1500 1707 0016 0100 106a  ...............j
00000d0: 6176 612f 6c61 6e67 2f53 7973 7465 6d0c  ava/lang/System.
00000e0: 0018 0019 0100 036f 7574 0100 154c 6a61  .......out...Lja
00000f0: 7661 2f69 6f2f 5072 696e 7453 7472 6561  va/io/PrintStrea
0000100: 6d3b 0a00 1b00 1d07 001c 0100 106a 6176  m;...........jav
0000110: 612f 6c61 6e67 2f53 7472 696e 670c 001e  a/lang/String...
0000120: 001f 0100 066c 656e 6774 6801 0003 2829  .....length...()
0000130: 490a 0021 0023 0700 2201 0013 6a61 7661  I..!.#.."...java
0000140: 2f69 6f2f 5072 696e 7453 7472 6561 6d0c  /io/PrintStream.
0000150: 0024 0025 0100 0770 7269 6e74 6c6e 0100  .$.%...println..
0000160: 0428 4929 560a 001b 0027 0c00 2800 2901  .(I)V....'..(.).
0000170: 000b 746f 4368 6172 4172 7261 7901 0004  ..toCharArray...
0000180: 2829 5b43 0100 0461 7267 7301 0013 5b4c  ()[C...args...[L
0000190: 6a61 7661 2f6c 616e 672f 5374 7269 6e67  java/lang/String
00001a0: 3b01 0001 7301 0012 4c6a 6176 612f 6c61  ;...s...Ljava/la
00001b0: 6e67 2f53 7472 696e 673b 0100 0273 3101  ng/String;...s1.
00001c0: 000a 536f 7572 6365 4669 6c65 0100 1055  ..SourceFile...U
00001d0: 6e69 636f 6465 5465 7374 2e6a 6176 6100  nicodeTest.java.
00001e0: 2100 0100 0300 0000 0000 0200 0100 0500  !...............
00001f0: 0600 0100 0700 0000 2f00 0100 0100 0000  ......../.......
0000200: 052a b700 08b1 0000 0002 000a 0000 0006  .*..............
0000210: 0001 0000 0002 000b 0000 000c 0001 0000  ................
0000220: 0005 000c 000d 0000 0009 000e 000f 0001  ................
0000230: 0007 0000 0078 0002 0003 0000 0026 1210  .....x.......&..
0000240: 4c12 124d b200 142b b600 1ab6 0020 b200  L..M...+..... ..
0000250: 142c b600 1ab6 0020 b200 142c b600 26be  .,..... ...,..&.
0000260: b600 20b1 0000 0002 000a 0000 001a 0006  .. .............
0000270: 0000 0005 0003 0006 0006 0007 0010 0008  ................
0000280: 001a 0009 0025 000a 000b 0000 0020 0003  .....%....... ..
0000290: 0000 0026 002a 002b 0000 0003 0023 002c  ...&.*.+.....#.,
00002a0: 002d 0001 0006 0020 002e 002d 0002 0001  .-..... ...-....
00002b0: 002f 0000 0002 0030                      ./.....0
```

I have found the Chinese character "中" in line 12 `03e4 b8ad`, unicode U+4E2D, which in UTF-8 is `E4 B8 AD`, but I can't find another character "", unicode U+29100, which I expected something like "04 F0 A9 84 80", why?

Comment: U+29100 is represented in UTF-16 as `\uD864\uDD00`, did you search for those bytes?

Comment: Yes I did, not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html).

Compile first with 
`javac UnicodeTest.java`

Then disassemble with
`javap -v UnicodeTest.class` (truncated to relevant part) :

```
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #9.#18         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = String             #19            // 中
   #3 = String             #20            // 
   #4 = Fieldref           #21.#22        // 
... truncated
  #17 = Utf8               UnicodeTest.java
  #18 = NameAndType        #10:#11        // "<init>":()V
  #19 = Utf8               中
  #20 = Utf8
```

Item #20 in constant pool is what you are looking for.

Now, you let's check [JVM class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html).

`Utf8` datastructure is [CONSTANT_Utf8_info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7)

```
CONSTANT_Utf8_info {
    u1 tag;
    u2 length;
    u1 bytes[length];
}
```

tag is CONSTANT_Utf8 (`01`). length is `00 06`, bytes are `ed a1 a4 ed b4 80`

According to unicode lookup, mentioned character should have codepoint 0x29100.

Now back to JVM spec.

> Characters with code points above U+FFFF (so-called supplementary
>   characters) are represented by separately encoding the two surrogate
>   code units of their UTF-16 representation. Each of the surrogate code
>   units is represented by three bytes. This means supplementary
>   characters are represented by six bytes, u, v, w, x, y, and z :

*I will not paste content here because it's too long, but you can look it up as Table 4.12. under CONSTANT_Utf8_info info (link above)*

So that's why it is 6 bytes long.

Now let's take the formula

```
0x10000 + ((v & 0x0f) << 16) + ((w & 0x3f) << 10) +
((y & 0x0f) << 6) + (z & 0x3f)
```

By substituting `v`, `w` ,`y` and `z` output is 168192(10) which is **0x29100**, which is expected code point.

Comment: To elaborate on the JVM spec, what it described is more formally known as [Modified UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8), which is described in a little more detail in the Java documentation of the [`DataInput` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html)

Answer (score 1):

The classic technique you can use to find that out is changing the value by something else and check the hex-dump for the difference. This was already used in the eighties when you "hacked" save games for games to increase e.g. attributes of your role playing character, etc.

I changed the character by `a` and it seems that the character can be found at offset 0xBE-0xC3 and has the value `ED A1 A4 ED B4 80`. I would have to look up the specifics of this to be able to explain why the value differs from the one you expected but Java's original support for Unicode was limited to two bytes (that's what the `char` type is defined. Unicode-characters with a 3+ bytes or more need to be encoded in a particular way in the Bytecode to tell the ClassLoader that it needs to be treated in a different way.